# How to create sectioned adapter with LoadManager

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

Here is example with use of LoadManager
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html

example of sectioned adapter is

private class SectionAdapter extends SectionedAdapter {

```
@Override
protected View getHeaderView(String caption, int index,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView tv = new TextView(LazySectionListActivity.this);
    tv.setText(caption);
    return tv;
}
```

}

My problem with LoadManager is that I can not fetch date from separate cursors :(,
namely I need to fill the listview with data from two separate cursors and they should be separated in the listview with some header (just like with the sectioned adapter)

how can I display data from separate cursors in the same listview with use of LoadManager

so far I managed to make workable example with only one cursor in the onCreateLoader method

```
   public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        Uri baseUri;
            baseUri = Contacts.CONTENT_URI;

        String select = "((" + Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " NOTNULL) AND ("
                + Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1) AND ("
                + Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " != '' ))";
        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), baseUri,
                CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION, select, null,
                Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
    }
```

But I need to display data from two separate cursors

I know that I can not have two return statements , but I am trying to illustrate the problem that I do not know how to solve it

```
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        Uri baseUri;
            baseUri = Contacts.CONTENT_URI;

        String select = "((" + Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " NOTNULL) AND ("
                + Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1) AND ("
                + Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " != '' ))";
        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), baseUri,
                CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION, select, null,
                Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
//beside the first cursor data that I want to be displayed 
//I also want the date from the second cursor 
        Uri baseUri2;
            baseUri = "some other uri";

        String select2 = "some other select";
        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), baseUri2,
                        projection, select2, null,
                MyClass.BlaBla + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
    }
```